# ¿Cómo obtener valores de la URL (GET) en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

En muchas ocasiones he requerido de tomar un valor proporcionado por la `URL` para llevar a cabo alguna acción o simplemente para imprimir al usuario dichos datos sin necesidad de pasar por un lenguaje del lado del servidor (ya sea `Python`, `PHP`, `Ruby`, entre otros).

> ¿Cuál es la mejor solución?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

En JavaScript no existen funciones intrínsecas que nos permiten obtener los valores de parámetros GET como es el caso de lenguajes como PHP que pueden obtener dichos valores de la variable global `$GET`. En cambio se puede hacer uso de las expresiones regulares para lograr un resultado que simule dicho comportamiento y obtener un valor esperado.

#### Solución

En la siguiente url (inglés) podemos obtener una función de apoyo: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Citando la fuente original de la liga anterior, tenemos que:

```
/**
 * @param String name
 * @return String
 */
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

#### Uso

Tomando en cuenta que tenemos una URL como la siguiente:

```
http://www.ejemplo.com.mx/producto?prodId=88
```

El valor a obtener sería **88** y lo obtendríamos con:

```
var prodId = getParameterByName('prodId');
```

#### Explicación

La función *getParameterByName* recibe un parámetro del tipo **String** (cadena de texto) que va a ser utilizado para evaluar por medio de una expresión regular que busque todo el contenido entre el final de la cadena recibida seguido por un símbolo de igual (=) y el final de la cadena a donde buscar (`location.search`) o hasta encontrar el símbolo «et» también conocido como «ampersand» (&). Al final dicho texto encontrado decodificado y devuelto. En el remoto caso de no encontrar coincidencias, devolverá una cadena vacía.

Comment: Muy bueno el el ejemplo. [Dejo otro](https://gist.github.com/ryoppy/5780748) realizado con underscore.js (y con test en Jasmine)

Answer (score 10):

Yo vengo usando ya hace algún tiempo la función creada por [Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/author/chriscoyier/), me va muy bien, no he tenido problemas y no usa expresiones regulares:

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var vars = query.split("&");
   for (var i=0; i < vars.length; i++) {
       var pair = vars[i].split("=");
       if(pair[0] == variable) {
           return pair[1];
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```

**Ejemplo**:

URL: http://store.com/shop.php?product_id=32&cat_id=1&sessionid=123

```html
<div>
    <button type="button" onclick="alert(getQueryVariable('sessionid'));">
        sessionid
    </button>
    <button type="button" onclick="alert(getQueryVariable('xyz'));">
        xyz
    </button>
    <button type="button" onclick="alert(getQueryVariable('product_id'));">
        product_id 
    </button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getQueryVariable(variable) {
        // Estoy asumiendo que query es window.location.search.substring(1);
        var query = "product_id=32&cat_id=1&sessionid=123";
        var vars = query.split("&");
        alert(vars);
        for (var i=0; i < vars.length; i++) {
            var pair = vars[i].split("="); 
            if (pair[0] == variable) {
                return pair[1];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

### Referencias:

- [Get URL Variables](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/)

Answer (score 5):

```
let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
var contract = params.get('contrato');
```

Bueno, a mi esto me ha funcionado bien

La interfaz URLSearchParams define métodos útiles para trabajar con los parámetros de búsqueda de una URL.

[Referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], tu respuesta podría ser marcada como de baja calidad pues es solo código sin explicación alguna

Comment: @Aprendiz ya lo arreglé, mira bien :)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes evitar usar Regex o similares soluciones, usando **`URLSearchParams`**.
Puedes revisar la documentación en [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) para más información sobre compatibilidad y demás.

```js
const url = new URL('http://midominio.com/ruta/?param1=valor1&param2=valor2')

const searchParams = url.searchParams

const keys = [...searchParams.keys()]

const object1 = keys
  .reduce((obj, key) =>({...obj, [key]: searchParams.get(key) }), {})
  
const object2 = [...searchParams.entries()]
  .reduce((obj, [key, value]) => ({...obj, [key]: value }), {})

console.log(object1)
console.log(object2)

// [[key1, value1], ...]
console.log([...searchParams.entries()])
// [key1, key2, ...]
console.log([...searchParams.keys()])
// [value1, value2, ...]
console.log([...searchParams.values()])
```

**NOTA:**
El código implementado puede no funcionar en algunos navegadores.

Answer (score -3):

Aquí en su momento programe una extensión para jquery que le los parámetros tanto en resful como con url no amigables en el readme están las instrucciones

https://github.com/marcmayol/jquery_extension_url_reader