# Obtener los parametros y verificar si existe

Tags: javascript, html

Bueno quiero saber como puedo obtener los parámetros se hacerlo con `node.js` pero no con `html` o `javascript`.

> - localhost/match/51252134213
> - localhost/match/PARAMETRO

Comment: los parametros get?

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Gaston, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado, saludos!

Comment: En esta respuesta que ya dieron explican muy bien https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/445/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-valores-de-la-url-get-en-javascript

Comment: Eso ya lo savia , pero me refiero a como puedo poner un path/ para que sea localhost/aquielpath/yaquielparametro

Comment: Esta pregunta la vuelves a realizar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/125196/como-obtener-los-parametros

Answer (score -1):

si deseas leer el ultimo parametro despues del "/" podrias usar este codigo de javascript, me comentas si eso es lo que necesitas.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getparameters01(){
        var strURL = window.location.href ;
        alert(strURL);
        var vParametros = strURL.split('/');
            alert(vParametros[vParametros.length-1]);
    }
    getparameters01();
</script>
```

Comment: Ya pero quiero que sea asi localhost/aqui el path / aqui el parametro

Comment: Ademas el xamp me da un error de 404