# Como obtener parámetros desde la ruta a la que se accede a un PHP

Tags: php, apache

Quería saber si es posible obtener los parámetros con un `path`

Algo así:

> localhost/pathaqui/parametroaqui

Por ejemplo:

> localhost/match/520201204

donde `520201204` es el parámetro que quiero obtener dentro del archivo `/match/index.php`.

¿Existe alguna forma de acceder así, y que el archivo PHP reciba esa parte de la ruta como parámetro?

Comment: Te invito nuevamente a leer [ask] para formular tu pregunta evita realizar la misma pregunta varias veces: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/125181/obtener-los-parametros-y-verificar-si-existe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Debes usar el archivo `.htaccess` de tu servidor***

Sigue este ejemplo:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [NC,L]
```

Esto significa basicamente que si una URL es formateada de acuerdo a las expresiones regulares de arriba (numero - slash - alfanumérico,guiones y subguiones) entonces el contenido dedebería ser mostrado de index.php y pasarse los dos parametros llamados `var1` y `var2`, teniendo `var1` el valor del numero y `var2`el valor de lo ingresado despues del slash

Ejemplo:

```
mysite.com/20/this_is_a_new_article/
```

Significaría:

```
mysite.com?var1=20&var2=this_is_a_new_article
```

Claro que, podrías simplemente tomar los valores usando dentro de `index.php` usando

```
$var1 = $_GET['var1'];
$var2 = $_GET['var2'];
```

#### NOTAS

- Esta respuesta es básicamente una traducción de [la respuesta más apropiada de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901635/php-passing-parameters-via-url), que en su momento a mí me ayudo a resolver un problema similar.
- Este método no generará errores 404 si está bien configurado.
- Revisa y edita tu pregunta para que obtengas más y mejores respuestas, además de permitir a personas con el mismo problema encontrar más fácilmente una solucion.

Comment: Vale si anda pero http://127.0.0.1/20/this_is_a_new_article/ como hago para que el 20 sea palabras ?

Comment: Yo tambien usé esa respuesta, pero no se exactamente como sería el caso que tu quieres, probablemente sería algo asi: 


`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [NC,L]`

Es cuestión de probar un poco.

Comment: Si , funciona perfecto gracias

Comment: En ese caso, acepta la respuewsta por favor

Suerte :)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener los parámetros de la ruta usando [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php) y luego convirtiendolo a un array con [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php). En el ejemplo también incluí un [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.trim.php) para quitar las barras del principio y final.

```
<?php

$params = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'));

if ($params[0] == 'match')
  $match = $params[1];

if (isset($match))
  echo $match;


/*
  http://localhost/match/123456

  $params[0] => 'match'
  $params[1] => 123456

  Imprime '123456'
*/

/*
  http://localhost/

  $params[0] => NULL
  $params[1] => NULL

  No imprime nada
*/
```

Comment: Sabes como solucionar el error 404 con parametros ?