# como hago para que no se borren los campos del formulario sin php

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

- tengo un formulario y quiero que cuando el visitante ingrese sus datos y le de "enviar" no se borren si no que sigan ahí y pueda decidir si enviar otro correo con los mismo datos o comenzar a borrarlos para escribir otros, como lo logro sin php?

codigo:

```html
<div class='contact-form-widget'>
    <div class='form'>
      <form name='contact-form'>
        <p/>
        <data:contactFormNameMsg/>
        <br/>
        <input class='contact-form-name' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_contact-form-name&quot;' name='name' size='30' type='text' value=''/>
        <p/>
        <data:contactFormEmailMsg/> <span style='font-weight: bolder;'>*</span>
        <br/>
        <input class='contact-form-email' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_contact-form-email&quot;' name='email' size='30' type='text' value=''/>
        <p/>
        <data:contactFormMessageMsg/> <span style='font-weight: bolder;'>*</span>
        <br/>
        <textarea class='contact-form-email-message' cols='25' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_contact-form-email-message&quot;' name='email-message' rows='5'/>
        <p/>
        <input class='contact-form-button contact-form-button-submit' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_contact-form-submit&quot;' expr:value='data:contactFormSendMsg' type='button'/>
        <p/>
        <div style='text-align: center; max-width: 222px; width: 100%'>
          <p class='contact-form-error-message' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_contact-form-error-message&quot;'/>
          <p class='contact-form-success-message' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_contact-form-success-message&quot;'/>
        </div>
      </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes enviar los datos por GET en el formulario,

```
<form name='contact-form' method='GET'>
```

Y con javascript obtener los datos de la URL:

```js
   
    //prueba
    alert(getQueryVariable('product_id'))
    //funcion
        function getQueryVariable(variable) {
            // Estoy asumiendo que query es window.location.search.substring(1);
            var query = "product_id=32&cat_id=1&sessionid=123";
            var vars = query.split("&");
            //alert(vars);
            for (var i=0; i < vars.length; i++) {
                var pair = vars[i].split("="); 
                if (pair[0] == variable) {
                    return pair[1];
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

obtener get tomado de:
([¿Cómo obtener valores de la URL (GET) en JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/445/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-valores-de-la-url-get-en-javascript))

***DE ESTA MANERA:***
Ya con javascript le asignas automaticamente el valor a cada campo del formulario.

Comment: En product id lo dejo como está?

Comment: Es solo un ejemplo tu pon, getQueryVariable('variableQueNecesitas')

Comment: y  pones en query: var query = window.location.search.substring(1);