# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el GET del editor desde una URL amigable?

Tags: php

No logro detectar el identificador de `editor` desde las URL amigables.

Mis URL amigables constan con varias categorías, no existe un número exacto, unas pueden tener más otras pueden tener menos categorías.

Ejemplo:

```
http://sitio.com/categoria1/categoría2/cat/cat/url-del-contenido-final/
```

Al darle al usuario su código de editor `pub-1374077Q` para registrar las referencia que fue promocionado desde su identificador, de la siguiente manera:

```
http://sitio.com/categoria1/categoría2/cat/cat/url-del-contenido-final/?publishers=pub-1374077Q
```

Pero no me imprime su identificador desde la URL amigable

```
$publishers = $_GET['publishers'];
echo $publishers;
```

Desde una URL normal:

```
http://sitio.com/index.php?publishers=pub-1374077Q
```

Ahí me imprime su identificador `pub-1374077Q`

¿Pero como puedo obtener el identificador del editor desde las URL amigables?

Comment: revisaste este link? talves te pueda servir: 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/445/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-valores-de-la-url-get-en-javascript

Comment: @FranciscoAcevedo Es una buena explicación, pero está en javascript a mi me gusta más trabajar con PHP :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeramente debemos obtener la URL completa:

```
$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Luego la mejor manera de obtener lo que deseas es hacerlo mediante [explode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) para eliminar cierta parte de la url, en este caso el `/?publishers=` y mediante [array_pop](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-pop.php) para obtener el último elemento del final, del array `pub-1374077Q`.

```
$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = explode('/?publishers=', $url);
$lastPart = array_pop($url);
echo $lastPart;
```