# Como obtengo los datos de una variable enviada?

Tags: javascript, html

Envío desde una función js una variable llamada cadena, como la recibo en otro html?

```
window.location.href='https://phenomeni.000webhostapp.com/proyecto/pageInicio.html?cadena='+ cadena;
```

Como la obtengo en el otro html en una función js?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/445/cómo-obtener-valores-de-la-url-get-en-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Parece que lo que tratas de hacer es capturar/enviar datos a través de "[Query String](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)", para lo cual he hecho el siguiente código:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  // Verificar que el parametro existe
  const exists = urlParams.has('cadena');
  if (exists) {
    // Obtenemos el valor
    const value = urlParams.get('cadena');
    // Mostramos el valor al cliente
    alert(`Valor del parámetro: ${value}`);
  }
}
```

Suponiendo que la url es `https://phenomeni.000webhostapp.com/proyecto/pageInicio.html?cadena=hola`, se mostrará un "alert" con el texto: `"Valor del parámetro: hola"`.

Answer (score 0):

Hola no estoy tan seguro pero creo que puedes guardar la locación en una variable y luego eliminar lo que no necesitas del texto solo quedándote con los datos que necesites

En el otro HTML pones esto en un archivo en js para capturar la variable que pasaste por la url

```
//Aqui capturas la url en una variable
var locacion = window.location.href
//En esta eliminas los datos que no nesesitas quedandote con la variable
var datos_capturados = locacion.replace('https://phenomeni.000webhostapp.com/proyecto/pageInicio.html?cadena=', '')
console.log(datos_capturados)
```