# Cargar datos en datatable mediante una consulta select WHERE con $_GET pasado a traves de un formulario

Tags: php, html, ajax, datatable, get

Tengo un formulario que envia por GET un valor
 - localhost/test/testlist.php?codov=2222
Intento coger el valor por GET desde test.php para rellenar la tabla pero algo debo estar haciendo mal, o mal planteado. Porfavor si alguien me puede ayudar estaría eternamente agradecido.
Despues de poner en el form del index un numero y darle a enter aparezco en localhost/test/testlist.php?codov=2222 y necesito que el "2222" pase a test.php para realizar la consulta y poder mostrar el contenido de 2222 en la datatable

Esto es testlist.php

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //var codov = $.urlParam("codov");
            //console.log(codov);
            listar();
        });
        var listar = function(){
            var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
                "ajax":{
                    "method":"POST",
                    "url":"test.php"
                },
                 "columns": [
                    { "data": 'CodArt' } ,
                    { "data": 'NombreArt' },
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="mytable" class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Código</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

y esto seria test.php pero con consigo que por GET me coja el valor que le dio en el primer form.

```
<?php
include_once("DbConnect.php");


$sql = "SELECT 
            req.id as IdArt, 
            req.item as CodArt, 
            req.qty_req as Requerido,
            req.sales_order as Ov,
            concat_ws(' ',stk.itm_name_1,' ',stk.itm_name_2, ' ',stk.itm_name_3) as NombreArt,
            ifnull(SUM(iss.quantity),0)  as Consumido,
            ifnull((select sum(soh.quantity) from mapubli.soh soh where soh.item=req.item),0) as StockActual
            FROM 
                mapubli.so sales
            INNER JOIN
                mapubli.req req ON sales.num = req.sales_order
            INNER JOIN 
                mapubli.stkitm stk ON stk.itm_code = req.item
            LEFT JOIN 
                mapubli_proy.mpl_web_iss iss ON req.id = iss.req_id
            where sales.num = 1909612
                group by req.id
                order by req.item";


            $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
            echo $sql;

            if ( !$result ){
                die("ERROR");
            }else{
                while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $arreglo["data"][] = $data;
                }
                echo json_encode($arreglo);

            }

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: Tu inconveniente es que realizas el envío por **POST** y no por **GET** `"ajax":{
                    "method":"POST",
                    "url":"test.php"
                },`

Answer (score -1):

Tu inconveniente es que realizas el envío por **POST** y no por **GET**

```
"ajax":{
    "method":"POST",
    "url":"test.php"
},
```

Para obtener el parámetro `codov` de la URL, utilice [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) tomándolo de esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/263443/52028)

Una solución seria enviar el dato necesario vía **`data`** en el Ajax.
Mas detalles de [Data](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        listar();
    });
    var listar = function(){
        var params = new URLSearchParams(location.search); //retorna un objeto de tipo URLSearchParams
        var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
            "ajax":{
                "method":"POST",
                "url":"test.php",
                "data": {
                    "codov": params.get('codov');
                }
            },
             "columns": [
                { "data": 'CodArt' } ,
                { "data": 'NombreArt' },
    }
</script>
```

Y en tu archivo test.php recibes vía POST la variable

```
<?php
include_once("DbConnect.php");

$codov = $_POST['codov'];

//Sugiero que valides si $codov es un código permitido

//Lo utilizas en el select
$sql = "SELECT ...
```

Comment: $.urlParam me indica que no es una funcion y no me coge nada.

Comment: @FranQuiros Edite la respuesta agregando otra forma de obtener la URL