# Como enviar datos de variable php a html

Tags: php, html

Buenas soy nuevo en php he estado repasando documentos al respecto pero no puedo resolver esto. Realice una conexión a una base de datos y logre registrar a un usuario en php, pero lo que quiero es que al registrarse se envié a la pagina con el "$nombre" de usuario para enviar un mensaje de bienvenida.

```
<?php 
//Realiza la conexion con la BD Oracle
$cone = oci_connect("buenosaires", "123456", "localhost/XE");

//Añadimos a las variables los datos desde la pag HTML por metodo POST
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$correo=$_POST['correo'];
$contrasena=$_POST['pass'];

//Realizamos una sentencia para hacer que el codigo aumente de 1 en 1
$sql=oci_parse($cone,"SELECT NVL(MAX(CODIGO),0)+1 AS CODIGO FROM USUARIO");
oci_execute($sql);

while (oci_fetch($sql)) {
    $maxcode= oci_result($sql, 'CODIGO');
}

//Sentencia para insertar valores en la base de datos
oci_free_statement($sql);
$sql= oci_parse($cone,"INSERT INTO USUARIO VALUES('$maxcode','$nombre','$contrasena',1,'$correo')");
$ejecutar= oci_execute($sql);
oci_close($cone);

if (!$ejecutar) {
    echo"ERROR CRITICO";
}else{
    //ACÁ SE ENVÍA A LA PAGINA DONDE QUIERO PASAR LA VARIABLE $NOMBRE
    header("Location: /Web Buenos Aires/paso.html");   
}
?>
```

Encontré una forma de hacerlo, pero me piden que cambie el formato .html a la pagina de destino por .php pero necesito dejarla en .html disculpen por mi redacción o por como exprese la pregunta estoy empezando en esta plataforma.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/445/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-valores-de-la-url-get-en-javascript

Comment: Recomiendo que la sintaxis para la base datos la dejes en una variable y validar si la sentencia que dejo en la variable es correcto para la base datos.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo por lo que decís que deberías pasar al menos una variable a la página `HTML` que se encuentra en  `/Web Buenos Aires/paso.html`.

Primero aclaremos que cuando decimos **HTML** estamos hablando de un **lenguaje de marcado** para presentar texto con etiquetas y no un lenguaje de programación, por lo tanto no podremos pasarle variables como en **PHP**.

### Pasar una variable PHP hacia HTML

El problema que tenemos es **HTML no puede recibir variables**.

```
header("Location: /Web Buenos Aires/paso.html");
```

La pagina **HTML** que tenemos como destino es `paso.html`. Esta linea de código sigue igual.

**Iniciamos**, creando la página `paso.php` y el archivo `.htaccess` si aun no lo tenemos.

#### Insertamos reglas en .htaccess

Colocamos la regla de escritura para que al ingresar a la página `paso.html` nos devuelva `paso.php`.

```
# Contenido htaccess
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^paso.html$ /paso.php [QSA]
```

#### Creamos paso.php

Creamos en el servidor el archivo `paso.php`. El contenido es generado con PHP pero, nuestra idea es devolver su contenido en `HTML`.

```
<?php
$nombre = "Juan"; // Ejemplo variable que viene de código anterior

// Colocamos el contenido con las etiquetas html y la variable $nombre
echo "Hola, mi nombre es <strong>$nombre</strong>";
?>
```

La visualización en el navegador de la página `paso.html` será este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Opción adicional pasando variable por GET

Si llegara a ser necesario, también podemos pasarle por `GET` a `paso.html`

```
header("Location: /Web Buenos Aires/paso.html?nombre=$nombre);
```

Mostramos el contenido de `paso.html?nombre=$nombre`

```
<?php
$nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
echo "Hola, mi nombre es <strong>$nombre</strong>";
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

añade a esta parte del codigo lo siguiente

```
    oci_free_statement($sql);
    $sql= oci_parse($cone,"INSERT INTO USUARIO VALUES('$maxcode','$nombre','$contrasena',1,'$correo')");
    $ejecutar= oci_execute($sql);
    oci_close($cone);
//Esto lo añadi yo
$ID = oci_close($cone)->LastinsertId();
```

y lo llamas en html con javascript (no recuerdo muy bien la sintaxis)